# If Id does not come, it returns an error, but if Id does not come, I want it to redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image]

If Id does not come, it returns an error, but if Id does not come, I want it to redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Id` argument as optional somehow.

Either:

- Give it a default value: `Guid Id = Guid.Empty`, and check in the body of the method whether it is in fact `Guid.Empty`.
- Make it nullable: `Guid? Id`, and add a null-check

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your `id` as nullable:

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid? id)
{
  if (!id.HasValue)
    return RedirectToAction( /* ... * ); // or some other form of redirect
  // ... access value of id like this: id.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter nullable:

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid? id)
```

And redirect if it's `null`:

```
if (id == null)
    return RedirectToAction("SomeAction");
```